# Oracle SqlDeveloper can not find correct JDK

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to install Oracle SQLDeveloper4 on my windows7 machine.

I set JAVA_HOME to point my jdk 1.7,
I add to my PATH variable %JAVA_HOME%/bin. When I echo and java -version I can see it is Java 1.7 and when I echo I can see it is in the %PATH%

I even set it in its sqlDeveloper.conf file to point to my jdk1.7;

```
 SetJavaHome C:\Java\jdk1.7
```

**BUT STILL** Whenever I run the sqldeveloper.exe I get warning saying it can not run on Java 1.6 and it needs Java1.7 !!

How can I get this stupid thing installed on my machine?? very frustrating..

Comment: At the end of my sqldeveloper.conf i have IncludeConfFile sqldeveloper-nondebug.conf . Do you include any other .confs that are changing java home?

Comment: @Carlos Bribiescas no there is not

Comment: Which version of 1.7 do have - I think it needs at least 1.7.0_25, but I can't immediately remember where I've got that from. Possibly you have a lower patch level and the error message is just misleading? (Actually... [1.7.0_45 for the latest version](https://community.oracle.com/message/12322622#12322622))

Comment: Exit out of SQL Developer 4. 

In appdata%\..\Roaming\SQL Developer that has a system4 folder which you can rename to something else

There is also another folder in %appdata%\..\Roaming called sqldeveloper ... Rename to something else. 

When I run SQL Developer 4 again, I get prompted to select a JavaHome path. After I choose a directory, product.conf is updated with the JavaHome updated in the file.

By the way, I'm using 1.7.0_51

Comment: @AlexPoole - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-releasenotes-v4-1925251.html -- Is this where you are getting 1.7.0_25 figure? JDK Support
Oracle SQL Developer 4.0 release supports java version 1.7 and above
If SQL Developer cannot find a local JDK, you will be prompted to enter the location path for the JDK. Note that the prompt wants only the folder, not the java.exe.  For example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

Comment: @SunWKim - maybe, I'd seen that before adding my comment, and I currently have that version in my conf file. I thought I'd seen it stated somewhere more definitively than in that example though. Manually setting `SetJavaHome` as Spring has already done ought to work as well as selecting the value from a fresh install though.

Comment: @Spring - another thought; if you had version 3 installed before, are you using a shortcut that has the wrong 'start in' path? Clucthing at straws clearly, but that could be picking up the old `product.conf` and thus an old `SetJavaHome` pointing to 1.6?

Comment: @Alex Poole tnx for suggesitons, no I dont have version 3 installed

Comment: @Sun W Kim I also tried to point to the jdk which comes in the sqldeveloper zip folder and setJavaHome from my conf file, not worked..

Comment: @Sun W Kim I am not clear which appdata directory you are talking about? could you explain a bit more, doing this solved your problem?

Comment: In SQL Developer do Help -> About, properties page, what is `java.home` set to? Note some configuration settings are stored in a directory like `C:\Program Files\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin` in a file called `sqldeveloper.conf`.

Comment: Unless you downloaded SQL Developer 4 64-bit which comes with JDK 1.7 64-bit, you have to download and install JDK 1.7 32-bit separately.

Comment: @Brian I can not install sqldeveloper, so I cant open the help tab

Comment: There is no installer. You drop the files in a directory and run it. The first time it runs it may ask for the location of Java. The nice and short `installation notes` cover this.

Comment: Bit late now, but I just noticed you said you'd set `setJavaHome` in `sqldeveloper.conf`, presumably in the `bin` directory; so you replaced the default value of `..\..\jdk`? Once you've launched SQL Developer it will create a `product.conf` file under `AppData\Roaming` in your home directory, and it's the value in there you needed to change I think. Impossible to verify now though since it's working, but I'd guess you picked somehow picked the IBM JDK1 .6 at some point and it stuck. Not sure why it's set in two places but `product.conf` seems to override `sqldeveloper.conf`.

Comment: @Alex Poole tnx good information, but I couldn't find product.conf under roaming directory

Comment: @Spring - on mine it's under `AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\1.0.0.0.0`. I have had version 3 on this Win7 PC before; but I removed that file before moving to 4.0.1. On launch it prompted for the JDK location and recreated that file with the selected path. You seem to be experiencing something different though.

Comment: @Alex Poole holy s*ht, yes it is there and still pointing to IBM JDK!!

Comment: @Spring - interesting; so it seems like the `product.conf` value only overrides the `sqldeveler.conf` value if it's valid? That probably means that if you quit, reset the `sqldeveloper.conf` value to the default `..\..\jdk` (which doesn't exist), then relaunch it'll prompt for the JDK location and store your selection in `product.conf`, replacing the duff IBM one. Probably. Maybe... (And looking back that's basically what SunWKim's first comment was referring to!)

Comment: @Alex Poole I am not really sure, but it never prompted me to enter anything, I deleted ibm, set java_home to java 7 and also set sqldeveloper.conf to java7 and it worked

Comment: @Spring - just for info, [the `product.conf` file is actually documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/appdev.40/e38414/intro.htm#CHDBJEAI), which I hadn't realised until I just stumbled on it looking for something else *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole I used Sysinternals ProcMon to see what files SQLDeveloper.exe were touching to arrive at my first answer. So, thanks to Mark Russinovich and Bryce Cogswell for their free invaluable tool. :)

Comment: AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\1.0.0.0.0\product.conf in my case.

Comment: I have had the same issue and I have solved it by going into C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\1.0.0.0.0 and changing SetJavaHome inside the file product.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be that there is an IBM JDK1.6 folder on some irrelevant directory for some other project..It was there **even** I uninstalled all other JDK's yesterday..Today I just deleted that JDK folder..than all of a sudden sqldeveloper found the java1.7 and started working..WTF=WTF

Answer (score 6):

Goto the file:
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\1.0.0.0.0\product.conf

In this file 
eg:
SetJavaHome <PATH>\jdk1.7.0_67